# No Shadows with HDRI Render

Tags: rendering, shadows, hdri

Even though the 3D Viewport suggests that shadows should be visible (though they might be blurry), I don't get any shadows in the render:

[image: scene and render window at the same time]

As can be seen, some faint shadows are there, but none in the final render. (I notice that I have rotated the HDRI a bit so it does not match with the render, but that should not matter. I tried different angles.)

Comment: Looks like you are not showing the shadow catcher in render. Check that I'm the outliner

Comment: I forgot to say that I have already set the plane to be "Shadow Catcher" in the outliner. (The tick box)

Comment: I solved the problem myself after a second look. "Show in Renders" has to be ticked in. (That tick box sits nearby the "Shadow Catcher" tick box.) Thanks Frederik for trying to help anyway.